# Discrepancy in computing time in air (2D projectile motion)

Tags: proof-verification, physics, projectile-motion

> A cannonball is fired from a cannon with a velocity of $24.0\,\frac{\mathrm m}{\mathrm s}$ at an angle of $40^\circ$ relative to the positive $x$-axis. It lands on the ground $56.6\,\mathrm m$ from where it was launched. How much time did the cannonball spend in the air? (Ignore air resistance.)

I can solve for the airtime $t$ by using either position equation:

$$\begin{cases}
x=v_0\cos40^\circ t\\[1ex]
y=v_0\sin40^\circ t-\frac g2t^2
\end{cases}$$

Applying the first equation, I get

$$56.6\,\mathrm m=\left(24.0\,\frac{\mathrm m}{\mathrm s}\right)\cos40^\circ t\implies t\approx3.08\,\mathrm s$$

On the other hand, applying the second equation, I get

$$\begin{align*}
0&=\left(24.0\,\frac{\mathrm m}{\mathrm s}\right)\sin40^\circ t-\frac g2t^2\\[1ex]
\implies0&=\left(24.0\,\frac{\mathrm m}{\mathrm s}\right)\sin40^\circ-\frac g2t\\[1ex]
\implies t&=\frac{2\left(24.0\,\frac{\mathrm m}{\mathrm s}\right)\sin40^\circ}g\approx3.15\,\mathrm s
\end{align*}$$

assuming $g=9.80\,\frac{\mathrm m}{\mathrm s^2}$. These differing times suggest to me that the cannon reached a distance along the ground of $56.6\,\mathrm m$ before it hits the ground. **What is the source of the discrepancy?**

My initial thought is that it has to do with what value of $g$ we agree to use. If I were to set $t=3.08\,\mathrm s$ as found in the $x$ equation and substitute this into the $y$ equation to solve for an unknown $g$, I find that the "correct" gravitational acceleration is closer to $10.0175\,\frac{\mathrm m}{\mathrm s^2}$.

Alternatively, I can consider the cannonball's vertical velocity $v_y=v_{0y}-gt$ to determine the time it takes to reach its peak height, at which point $v_y=0$:

$$0=\left(24.0\,\frac{\mathrm m}{\mathrm s}\right)\sin40^\circ-gt\implies t\approx1.57417\,\mathrm s$$

Then it should take the cannonball twice this time to reach the ground, which suggests that it would stay in the air for about $3.15\,\mathrm s$. **Is the result of any one of these equations more accurate?**

Perhaps I should just take the average of the two times I found?

Comment: What if it was not launched from the ground ($y(0) \neq 0$)?

Comment: No mention of initial conditions is made in the question, so I assume it starts at the origin $(0,0)$ and returns to the ground at the point $(56.6,0)$.

Comment: Well, I can't see any other possibility.

Comment: Assuming the launch height is the same as the landing height, the distance traveled will be $57.9$m and not $56.6$m

Comment: I see! Thanks for pointing that out. I'm guessing the author of the question neglected to say something like, "the cannonball is caught in a bucket 56.6 meters away," with the bucket situated at exactly the cannonball's height at that distance.

Comment: Yes, the landing height must be higher than the launch height in which case, for $56.6$m to be correct, the time of flight is indeed $3.08$ sec.